# Adding a table to an existing Database code first MVC 5 EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a VS 2013 MVC5 Web application. So far I have customised the default AspNetUser table by Migration. I am now trying to add a new table to the existing database. 
I have created a patient class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TestModel.Models
{
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string HCN { get; set; }

    public string GP { get; set; }

    public string MedHis { get; set; }

    public string Medication { get; set; }

    public string CurrentPrescription { get; set; }

    public string PresentRX { get; set; }
 }
}
```

And a Patient Configuration class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace TestModel.Models
{
public class PatientConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public PatientConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Patient");

        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("IntId");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.HCN).HasColumnName("strHCN");

        Property(x => x.GP).HasColumnName("strGP");

        Property(x => x.MedHis).HasColumnName("strMedHis");

        Property(x => x.Medication).HasColumnName("strMedication");

        Property(x => x.CurrentPrescription).HasColumnName("strCurrentPrescription");

        Property(x => x.PresentRX).HasColumnName("strPresentRX");

    }
 }
}
```

In the Identity Model I have added the PatientDbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public class PatientDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

    }
}
```

But when I enter "Add-Migrations Patient" The following migrations class is created without the Patient details

```
namespace TestModel.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class Patient3 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
}
```

I understand this is a very basic problem but as a beginner I am unsure where I am going wrong.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Why are you nesting a regular DBContext inside an IdentityDbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if this is because your `DbSet<Patients>` accessor is inside a DbContext (PatientDbContext) which is nested inside the ApplicationDbContext class.

Put the `DbSet<Patients>` accessor in the main ApplicationDbContext and remove the PatientDbContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```